# validate gregorian Date Input IE11

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-11

i tried to create an date input for a specific date calculation. But have some problems i don't know how to handle.

The needs are:

- gregorian input format (dd.mm.yyyy)
- automaticly setting date points (so that you just have to input die digits)
- compatible with IE11 in an isolated network area (no connection to the internet, just intranet)
- no invalidate date inputs while typing/auto correction (no 31.02.2017, 30.14.2017 etc. )

Calculating with the date is no problem, if the date is correct. But my solution has a performance problem. if i type to "fast" it is not setting the dots automaticly ans ist not checking if it is a valid date.
When i click into the input field i can delete field items, and can't set anymore the date points correct.

A datepicker is no good alternative because of a big range of possible dates (+-100 years needed) and a datepicker is always slower then typing.

Hope you can help me....

```
    <input type="text" id="inputStrafbeginn" autofocus MaxLength="10" onKeyUp="isNumberKey(event);" onblur="berechnungStrafzeit()">

    function dots(){
       var dateBox = document.getElementById('inputStrafbeginn')
       var chars = dateBox.value.length;
       var text = dateBox.value;

       if (chars == 1 || chars == 4 || chars == 7) {
           document.getElementById('errorOutputStrafbeginn').innerHTML=" (ddmmyyy)";
       }
       if (chars == 2) {
          if (text > 31 || text < 1)
          {
            dateBox.value = "";
            document.getElementById('errorOutputStrafbeginn').innerHTML="Kein gültiges Tagesdatum!";
          }
          else
          {
            dateBox.value = text + ".";
            document.getElementById('errorOutputStrafbeginn').innerHTML=" (ddmmyyy)";
          }

       }
       if (chars == 5) {
         var value=text.charAt(3)+text.charAt(4);
         if(value>12 || value < 1)
         {
           dateBox.value = text.charAt(0)+text.charAt(1)+".";
           document.getElementById('errorOutputStrafbeginn').innerHTML="Kein gültiges Monatsdatum!";
         }
        else
        {
          dateBox.value = text + ".";
          document.getElementById('errorOutputStrafbeginn').innerHTML=" (ddmmyyy)";
        }

       }

    }

    function isNumberKey(evt){
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode

       // CHECK IF NUMBER
       if((charCode >=48 && charCode<=57) || (charCode>=96 && charCode<=105)){
          //IF KEY IS A NUMBER CALL DOTS
          dots();
       }
       else if( charCode==8 || charCode==9){
          // LET LEFT RIGHT BACKSPACE AND DEL PASS charCode==37||charCode==39||charCode==46 ||
       }
       else{
          // BLOCK ALL OTHER KEYS
          evt.preventDefault();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I would have gone with a date type input and ignore the format since it will be client specific. IMHO i think it's better the UI will be diffrent but getting the value from the input will always be in the same ISO standard format

Comment: "gregorian" isn't a format, it's a [*calendar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). ;-) I think you're way over thinking this. Just let the user type the date, then deal with it. Trying to control the UI through HTML and JS is fraught and typically ends with a dysfunctional experience for at least some users. Blocking input and formatting as users type is seriously unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, if i could use ff & chrome i would prefer a regular date input. but everything compatible with ie11 is huge problem for me... Perhaps i should rethink the project... Anywy if someone has a good (compatible) solution, i want to hear it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timeout javascript instruction to "delay" and control the timing when an user set the date. If you combine this with onkeypress (to check if a number key is pressed) to make the user wait 1 second (for example) to press another key and so on.

I would suggest you to re-analize the datepicker option because you can customize the date range to what you want and it'll be always more interactive/dinamic than just setting the date with the number keys of the keyboard